# How do I modify the the following code to run on Matlab r2018a?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Matlab file exchange has an extremely useful mexed C function: sharedmatrix.m:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix

But unfortunately, it crashes on versions later than R2014.

This code is critical for my project which needs some features in R2018a. How do I modify this code to run with R2018a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That file relies on undocumented functionality. Since the internals of MATLAB changed significantly in R2018a, most of the undocumented knowledge that people used in writing this type of functions is no longer correct. This is the reason that this function crashes.

The community has not caught up with these recent changes, and will likely never do so. So I suspect that this function will never work on R2018a or newer.

On the other hand, this type of undocumented functionality is no longer needed, as new, documented functionality provides most of the stuff that was possible earlier only using undocumented functionality.

One of the comments in the File Exchange submission in question suggests you use [`memmapfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) instead:

> First save the large piece of data to a file, then memory map it:
>
> ```
> m = memmapfile(data_file_name,'Format','single','Writable',true);
> ```
>
> You can then call this memory mapped file from inside a parfor like so:
>
> ```
> parfor i = 1:N 
>    mm{i} = memmapfile(tl_data_name,'Format','single','Writable',true); 
>    result(i) = someFunction(mm{i}) 
> end
> ```
>
> — JohnDapper, 14 Jun 2017

(I have not tested this myself.)